# How can I set custom page width and height in TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to generate a PDF file from HTML content. I want to set the  page width and height to the custom values 400px and 300px.

I used the following code

```
 $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Where

- `PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION` is `p`;
- `PDF_UNIT` is `mm`;
- `PDF_PAGE_FORMAT` is `A6`.

Answer (score 13):

you could do:

```
$custom_layout = array($your_width, $your_height);
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, $custom_layout, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Comment: It works for the Label printing. Where i needed page size: 41mm, 89mm. I set it up as: `$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'mm', array('41','89'), true, 'UTF-8', false);`

Comment: Is there a way to set an INFINITE height to simulate print to a plotter / label printer?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of PDF_PAGE_FORMAT (or A6), you could use an array to specifiy width and height.

The 3rd argument of the TCPDF constructor accepts either a string like 'A4', 'A6', etc. or a two-element array containing the width and height (in the units defined in PDF_UNIT).

So basically:

```php
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, array(400, 300), true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to define a new page by name (a completely custom page that has no relation), then this is how:

1. Go to **/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_static.php**
2. Scroll to Line 478
3. Add your custom sized sheets in the same format

   ```
   public static function getPageSizeFromFormat($format) {
   switch (strtoupper($format)) {
       // ISO 216 A Series + 2 SIS 014711 extensions
       case 'A0' : {$pf = array( 2383.937, 3370.394); break;}
       case 'A1' : {$pf = array( 1683.780, 2383.937); break;}
       case 'A2' : {$pf = array( 1190.551, 1683.780); break;}
       case 'A3' : {$pf = array(  841.890, 1190.551); break;}
       case 'A4' : {$pf = array(  595.276,  841.890); break;}
       case 'A5' : {$pf = array(  419.528,  595.276); break;}
       case 'A6' : {$pf = array(  297.638,  419.528); break;}
   ```

Just add another case with your custom size.

```
        case 'SQUARE' : {$pf = array( 297.638, 297.638); break;}
        case 'SMALLSQUARE' : {$pf = array( 100.00, 100.00); break;}
```

Then use the normal constructor to call the new page:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, 'SQUARE', true, 'UTF-8', false);
```